# My Dynamic CKNotification won't register

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I am trying to set up a dynamic `CKNotification` for iOS in Objective-C, but it's failing to register notification.

Here is my code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"notify == %@",userentry2.text];
CKSubscription *newRecordSub = [[CKSubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:savefolder predicate:predicate options: CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordUpdate | CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation];
CKNotificationInfo *noteInfo = [CKNotificationInfo new];
noteInfo.alertBody=@"%@";
noteInfo.alertLocalizationArgs = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"message"];
noteInfo.shouldBadge = NO;
noteInfo.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
newRecordSub.notificationInfo = noteInfo;
CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [container publicCloudDatabase];
[publicDatabase saveSubscription:newRecordSub completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"didn't register new notif");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"registered new notif");
    }
}];
```

When I had just the alert body before, without the `alertLocalizationArgs`, it would register perfectly, but now that I've added the `alertLocalizationArgs` functionality it won't register.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use either `alertBody` or you use `alertLocalizationKey` and `alertLocalizationArgs`. You don't mix the two.

It's unclear what you want the message to be. Assigning `@[ @"message" ]` makes no sense in any case.

Either do:

```
noteInfo.alertBody = @"Some message you create";
```

or do:

```
noteInfo.alertLocalizationKey = @"Some Key in your Localized.strings file";
noteInfo.alertLocalizationArgs = @[ @"argument value 1", @"argument value 2" ];
```

where the localization arguments are values that get substituted like using `stringWithFormat:` in whatever value is associated with the localization key. The use of the args is only to be used if the localized value takes 1 or more arguments.

Comment: thanks so much, sorry i should have specified: "message" would be a key or field in a ckrecord.